# Node.js net socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm using the net module to create a listener but I've experienced some issues. I'm trying to make it wait till it's done writing the "text" to the client before the client can type again. If I'm not doing this and I hold in enter it'll just make you able to write enters between text leading to weird formatting etc.

So how could I make it wait till it's written to the client?

Code:

```
const net = require('net');
const server = new net.Server();

server.on('connection', async function (socket) {
    console.log("Client connected!");

    socket.on('data', async function (data) {
        socket.setEncoding('utf8');
        let input = data.toString().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        if (input == "echo")
            socket.write("$ ");
        else
            socket.write("invalid command");
    });
});

server.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log("listening");
});
```

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxkMF.jpg

Edit:
This is on localhost, let's say I'd host it on a server so there's a higher ping it's way worse.

Edit:
Here a picture from when it's hosted on a server:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIJOT.jpg

Edit:
I've tried using SSH instead of telnet and raw and got basically the same result now.

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh2l5.jpg

Code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var username = null;
var ssh2 = require('ssh2');

new ssh2.Server({
    hostKeys: [fs.readFileSync('ssh.key')]
}, function (client) {
    console.log('Client connected!');

    client.on('authentication', function (ctx) {

        if (ctx.method !== 'password') return ctx.reject(['password']);

        if (ctx.method === 'password') {
            username = ctx.username;

            console.log(username);
            console.log(ctx.password);
            ctx.accept();
        }
        else {
            console.log("rejected.");
            ctx.reject();
        }

    }).on('ready', function () {
        console.log('Client authenticated!');

        client.on('session', function (accept, reject) {
            var session = accept();

            session.once('shell', function (accept, reject, info) {
                var stream = accept();

                stream.write("$ ");

                stream.on('data', function (data) {

                    var args = data.toString().split(" ");
                    console.log(args);

                    switch (args[0]) {
                        case "echo":
                            args.shift();
                            stream.write(args.join(" ") + "\r\n");
                            break;
                        case "whoami":
                            stream.write(username + "\r\n");
                            break;
                        case "exit":
                            stream.exit(0);
                            stream.end();
                            stream = undefined;
                            break;
                        default:
                            stream.stderr.write(args[0] + ": No such command!\r\n");
                            break;
                    }
                    if (typeof stream != 'undefined') {
                        stream.write("$ ");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
}).listen(1337, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + this.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Very hard to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: How do you imagine a program to prevent a user from pressing a key? Strong force feedback? Electroshock?

Comment: I've seen projects where it doesn't "bug" when you spam enter. I assumed it waited till it wrote the data to the user and then allows you to write in your client again but guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. What this code does is simply buffering until `\n` enter is received from a client.

```js
const net = require("net");
const readline = require("readline");

const execCommand = (command, args, socket) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // to clear the terminal
      socket.write("\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f");
      socket.write(
        `Executed command: ${command} with args: ${args} and result was: ${Math.random()}`
      );
      socket.write('\n>')
      res();
    }, 3000);
  });
};

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  socket.write("Connected");
  // nice prompt
  socket.write("\n>");

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: socket,
    output: socket,
  });

  rl.on("line", (line) => {
    if (line.length === 0) {
      socket.write("No command to execute!");
      socket.write('\n>')
      return;
    }
    // destructuring command and args
    // E.g. command arg1 arg2 ....
    const [command, ...args] = line.split(" ");
    execCommand(command, args, socket);
  });
});

server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Tried this, basically same result.

Comment: How are you connecting to this server? You can test it by connecting using telnet. Like `telnet localhost 1337` from you command prompt or terminal

Comment: Using KiTTY or PuTTY

Comment: I've tried on localhost too, the result is better because I'm receiving the data faster but it still occurs now and then.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the result is better"? If you use telnet as I mentioned in my comment above, once the connection establishes you can type multiple characters then press enter. The server should respond back with all the characters you typed.

Comment: So let me explain, I've made a system that checks the command so if I just spam enter, it'll keep replying with unknown command. But because the server takes time to send me the data it still allows me to press enter resulting in putting an enter before it was able to send back unknown command. Using localhost reduces this delay a lot therefor it rarely happens but I wanna host it on a server for obvious reasons.

Comment: I tweaked my answer. Please see if this is more like what you want

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'll test.

Comment: Same issue. Anyhow, I moved onto GoLang, I'm using their socket and it works perfectly as I wanted.